# User table structure for registration and login system with email

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, authentication, registration

I want to know what is best table structure and indexes for users table (login by email and password) for best performance.
I don't want to use usernames.
I want to login with unique index (for better performance) with user email.

Maybe best performance will be unique index for email and password together.

Problem is that I want to be email indexed as unique for faster login.
But in this case bad user can prevent another user to register knowing his email.

The only idea I could think of some sort of unique email and password hash in one unique column. But I want know how its done the best.

Part of my user table index structure (DB is MySQL)

```
user_id   - PRIMARY
email     - UNIQUE
password
verified   (after verify email)
```

Comment: If you want to allow multiple registrations from the same email address but with different passwords, you *could* redefine the `UNIQUE` constraint over the composite `(email, password)`.  However, this won't work if you store a salted hash of the `password` (which you *really* should do), so I don't recommend it.  What is the threat you are trying to counter?  That an attacker registers using someone else's email address?  Won't the genuine user then receive the verification email and/or be able to obtain a reset password?  Is this a serious threat?

Comment: My thread was that I register your email address and now you couldnt register, becouse your email is in DB. BUT I tottaly forgot that you receive a verification email. I PUT cancel registration(I didnt register) link in this email and problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

Send verification email with link to cancel registration (I didnt register)